# bug not showing what has been changed when reviewing edits

Tags: bug, editing, suggested-edits, review

Here is what I get when I want to review the most recent item on "review edits":

[image]

Somehow the right hand site is missing. Question was by Haruboy15, edit by Learner. Any idea what is happening?

EDIT: The link is [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/36289)

Comment: Somehow three people managed to review it. I still cannot tell what changed, even [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/267652/revisions).

Comment: The before/after titles are `Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$ :` and `Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_n$ :`. We're looking into why the diff isn't displaying properly.